# C++: How to read specific number of bytes from a binary file and save it to uint16_t?

Tags: c++, file, input

So I got this problem, I'm not so skilled with working with files and I just started C++ class in college and for the first assignment basically I need to extract specific bytes from a binary file and then work with them further.

The binary file looks something like this:

```
01001001 01001001 00000101 00000000 00001010 00000000 00001100 00000000
00101101 00101110 00101111 00110000 00110001 00101000 00101001 00101010
...
```

Where the first 8B are 2B values of some managing properties. (ie. 0-2B is width, 2-4B is height, etc.)
And I need to read these 2B properties one by one and save their values into uint16_t variables. The furtherest I've gotten so far was with this:

```
int main(void) {
  fstream f1;
  uint16_t endian, width, height, format;

  f1.open("input_01.img", ios::in | ios::binary);

  f1.get((char*) &endian, 2);
  f1.get((char*) &width, 2);
  f1.get((char*) &height, 2);
  f1.get((char*) &format, 2);

  /*...*/
}
```

This code correctly reads the first 2B, but then for some reason it stops working... I'm not sure if I don't understand how the get() function works or if my approach is completely wrong...

Comment: I am not sure you can use cast of reference like this.

Comment: @vcloarec He's taking the address, no reference.

Comment: I don't think you should be using `f1.get()` it stops at `\n` chars. Try using `f1.read()`.

Comment: @Mirko,of course, I am tired ...

Comment: Sorry, my b. The '4' was just a typo 'cause in the assignment there are different files with different sizes of those managing props...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `read`, not `get`. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/ and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/

It clearly says:

> 2) c-string Extracts characters from the stream and stores them in s
>   as a c-string, until either (n-1) characters have been extracted or
>   the delimiting character is encountered: the delimiting character
>   being either the newline character ('\n') or delim (if this argument
>   is specified). The delimiting character is not extracted from the
>   input sequence if found, and remains there as the next character to be
>   extracted from the stream (see getline for an alternative that does
>   discard the delimiting character). A null character ('\0') is
>   automatically appended to the written sequence if n is greater than
>   zero, even if an empty string is extracted.

So you would be having problems because newlines and null are valid characters as part of a number in binary. Also because like tkausl said, you're reading 4 bytes instead of 2. And also because get appends a null after.

You could do:

```
int main(void) {
  fstream f1;
  uint16_t endian, width, height, format;

  f1.open("input_01.img", ios::in | ios::binary);

  f1.read((char*) &endian, sizeof(endian));
  f1.read((char*) &width, sizeof(width));
  f1.read((char*) &height, sizeof(height));
  f1.read((char*) &format, sizeof(format));

  /*...*/
}
```

In that way, compiler sets the size for you, given that `uint16_t` is correct.

Or even use a template:

```
template <class T, class U>
void readFromFile(T& f1, U& variable)
{
    f1.read((char*) &variable, sizeof(variable));
}
```

And then invoke it with:

```
  f1.open("input_01.img", ios::in | ios::binary);

  readFromFile(f1, endian);
  readFromFile(f1, width);
  readFromFile(f1, height);
  readFromFile(f1, format);
```

Another way, useful when you have several things to read is:

```
// Attribute packed works on GCC, on other compilers you 
// might need a pragma
struct __attribute__((packed)) FileStruct
{
    uint16_t endian= 0;
    uint16_t width= 0;
    uint16_t height= 0;
    uint16_t format= 0;
};
// We check structure size after declaring it; should be 8 bytes long
static_assert(sizeof(FileStruct) == 8, "Size error");
```

Then:

```
  FileStruct f;
  f1.open("input_01.img", ios::in | ios::binary);
  readFromFile(f1, f); // f.width has the width, f.format has format, etc.
```